# Does not comply with PDF/A when signing a document through Itext 5.5.5

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfa, pdftools

I am working on converting a PDF to PDF/A.
I already did this conversion through a paid PDFTools library, the result of the conversion I place it on this page that is responsible for validating whether it complies with the PDA/A standard https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx
Validating indicates that it meets the standard.
Once converted, the PDF will be signed with the Itext 5.5.5 library, however, if I used the validator again the PDF/A standard is no longer valid. The errors shown on the validator are the following:

```
The name object must be UTF-8 encoded.

A device-specific color space (DeviceGray) without an appropriate output intent is used.

The font Helvetica must be embedded.

The document does not conform to the requested standard.
```

When signing, information about the digital signature (such as a stamp) is added to the document; it is for this reason that it no longer meets the standard.
Started by eliminating each of these errors, I have already eliminated the Helvetica font error with the following code:

```
String path = Sign.class.getResource("helvetica.ttf").toExternalForm();
FontFactory.register(path);
BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont(path, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(base);
appearance.setLayer2Font(font);
```

However, I have not eliminated these two errors:

```
The name object must be UTF-8 encoded.

A device-specific color space (DeviceGray) without an appropriate output intent is used.

The document does not conform to the requested standard.
```

The error of the color space, I tried to eliminate it with the following code, but didn't help at all
because it keeps getting the error when I do the validation again.

```
path = Sign.class.getResource("sRGBColorSpaceProfile.icm").toExternalForm();
ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream(path));
stamper.getWriter().setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
```

I hope you can help me see how to eliminate the errors so that it complies with the PDF/A standard, or if there is another alternative that allows me to convert to PDF/A and then sign it with the Itext 5.5.5 library.

I appreciate the help you can give me.Thank you

**UPDATE**

This the code that I use to sign documents with the Itext 5.5.5 library.

```
String pkcs11Config = "name=NAME" + "\n" + "library=PATH";
ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
ks.load(null, password);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfInput);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfOutputTemp);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
String path = Sign.class.getResource("helvetica.ttf").toExternalForm();
FontFactory.register(path);
BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont(path, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(base);
appearance.setLayer2Font(font);

path = Sign.class.getResource("sRGBColorSpaceProfile.icm").toExternalForm();
ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream(path));
stamper.getWriter().setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);

        ...

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass);
ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(key, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null);
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, crlList, null, tsc, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried changing the PdfStamper to PdfAStamper, but when I try to sign a document it returns the following error:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: Annotation of type /Widget should have Contents key.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA2Checker.checkAnnotation(PdfA2Checker.java:707)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAChecker.checkPdfAConformance(PdfAChecker.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAConformanceImp.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfAConformanceImp.java:71)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3480)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3476)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.toPdf(PdfAnnotation.java:989)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.addToObjStm(PdfWriter.java:292)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:382)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:373)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:369)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:843)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.addAnnotation(PdfStamperImp.java:1395)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.addAnnotation(PdfStamperImp.java:1408)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:1285)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:243)
```

**UPDATE 3**

I updated the itext library from 5.5.5 to 5.5.13.1, and it worked better.

If I use the PdfStamper, I can sign the document but when I use the PDF/A validator, it returns the following errors:

```
Validating file "DOCUMENT.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-2a

     A device-specific color space (DeviceGray) without an appropriate output intent is used.

     The document does not conform to the requested standard.

The document contains device-specific color spaces.

The document does not conform to the PDF/A-2a standard.

Done.
```

The error that said: "The name object must be UTF-8 encoded." doesn't appear anymore.

Also, I tried to use the PdfStamper. When I try to sign a document it returns a different exception than before. This is the new exeption:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: DeviceGray shall only be used if a device independent DefaultGray colour space has been set when the DeviceGray colour space is used, or if a PDF/A OutputIntent is present.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA2Checker.close(PdfA2Checker.java:829)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAStamperImp.close(PdfAStamperImp.java:227)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:1348)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:244)
```

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show the signing code. E.g. is your `stamper` a mere `PdfStamper` or is it a `PdfAStamper`? It should be the latter. Furthermore, is there a reason you don't use the current 5.5.x version?

Comment: @mkl I updated the post with the signing code. I've already try with PdfAStamper instead of PdfStamper but it didn't works. I got the following excepción when I try to sign a document: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: Annotation of type /Widget should have Contents key.

Comment: @mkl Also I've already try with the current version of itext but it didn´t works.

Comment: First of all I think the better approach would be to try and make the `PdfAStamper` variant run. Also could you share the current result for analysis, to find out where exactly something is wrong?

Comment: @mkl I updated the post with the exception that I receive when I try to sign a document.

Comment: That conformance check has been relaxed in July 2015. That change has been released with iText 5.5.7. I think you should update to at least the newest 5.5.x version.

Comment: @mkl I'll try to update the library. If I use PdfStamper, there is no way to eliminate the errors of the validator, like I did with the error of the Helvetica font? These are the errors:
The name object must be UTF-8 encoded.
A device-specific color space (DeviceGray) without an appropriate output intent is used.

Comment: *"If I use PdfStamper, there is no way to eliminate the errors of the validator, like I did with the error of the Helvetica font?"* - I don't know. But you surely don't want to implement this just to sign a single file once, do you? And chances are that the regular `PdfStamper` damages different details in different base PDFs when signing. Most likely you'd have to fix new issues on a daily basis... Furthermore you have not shared the documents in question, so there is nothing to analyze...

Comment: @mkl Here is the document that complies with PDF/A-2A: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ecDHIEvkoG6t5iiiasZJdp-bXVI5xRvr/view?usp=sharing When I sign a document with the PdfStamper, here is the document that doesn´t complies with PDF/A-2A: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zeUvFoC5GmCp_jEtxmSrtSjx3sZNHHNS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found a cause for the "The name object must be UTF-8 encoded", in iText 5.5.5 the name in the signature Prop_Build dictionary is an ANSI encoded name; since iText 5.5.6 it is an UTF-8 encoded string. So we already have two issues that meanwhile have been fixed. Thus, please try again with a current iText versions and check the exact errors that now occur.

Comment: The signature appearance appears not to be generated specifically for PDF/A; in particular its text is not tagged. Thus, you'll likely have to build a completely custom appearance yourself with tagging information. Alternatively make your signature invisible as a first step.

Comment: @mkl I've already updated the iText library to the 5.5.13.1 version. It seems that it works better but still doesn´t complies with the PDF/A-2A. I updated the post with the newest results of the tests with the new version of the library